# Resize Recyclerview height after Bottomsheet open cause gaps between items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I am resizing a RecyclerView height after the user opens or closes a BottomSheet so the RecyclerView's height will be between a ToolBar and my BottomSheet.
The problem is when the height gets changed, while scrolling up or down it causes a big gap between the items - the gap is actually an item that got 0 width and bigger height then it should be and that's why it looks like a gap.

This is the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".RegisterActivity">

    <!-- includes the RecyclerView -->
    <include layout="@layout/activity_register_sheet_content" />

    <!-- includes the bottom sheet -->
    <include layout="@layout/register_bottom_sheet" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and java:

```
    bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = registerRecyclerView.getLayoutParams();

            if (newState == STATE_COLLAPSED) {
                params.height = originalRecyclerViewHeight;
                registerRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);

            } else if (newState == STATE_EXPANDED) {
                params.height = realRecyclerHeight - bottomSheet.getMeasuredHeightAndState();
                registerRecyclerView.setLayoutParams(params);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
        }
    });
```

I'm using this version of AppCompat:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: can your provide screen shot from your problem

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/ZVIJgFK

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust the height in the overridden `onSlide` method, using the float offset. As the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback#onSlide(android.view.View,%20float)) say, the float offset is:

> The new offset of this bottom sheet within [-1,1] range. Offset
>   increases as this bottom sheet is moving upward. From 0 to 1 the sheet
>   is between collapsed and expanded states and from -1 to 0 it is
>   between hidden and collapsed states.

You can get the value for the bottom sheet height via

```
    int padding = bottomSheet.getHeight();
```

You can then multiply it by the float offset to adjust heights as you wish. e.g.

```
int padding = bottomSheet.getHeight();

if (!Float.isNaN(slideOffset)) {
     padding *= (1 - Math.abs(slideOffset));            
}
```

Then use that value to set the height of the recycler view.

Comment: Thanks. the problem is that the gaps created when I clicks the items, only background color changed on item selected, but not when changing the RecyclerView height